# Change laptop Mac OS X wallpaper upon location

Tags: macos, applescript, wallpaper

I'd like to display different wallpapers regarding the physical location where I turn on my laptop. I.e.: at home I want to see Wallpaper-A and at office I want it to be Wallpaper-B.

Is there a way (an App, an AppleScript) that could detect laptop's location (i.e. wifi connection) and then update wallpaper?

I saw an AppleScript that allows to do so regarding time of the day: https://github.com/pipwerks/OS-X-Wallpaper-Changer

Comment: [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) is built for exactly this type of thing.

Comment: You could post the script that changed the wallpaper based on time, for a start. That's better than posting nothing at all. Also, you might want to explain what you have tried to solve the problem so far. -- I don't agree that this question is put on hold as off-topic. This question is definitely a programming question, it is just asked in a bad way.

Comment: Done. Sorry for doing it wrong in my very first post in this site. I don't agree it's a programming question as it can be solved with an App, or maybe with user settings that just I couldn't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on 10.9

```
set mySSID to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I|grep \" SSID: \"|cut -c 18-"

if mySSID is equal to "NETWORK_NAME" then
    tell application "Finder"
        set desktop picture to {"Macintosh HD:Users:USER_NAME:Desktop:IMAGE_NAME.jpg"} as alias
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Perfect. It does the work. Also the App ControlPlane work, too.